# What happens to the stream when an actorSubscriber dies?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

In Akka Streams (java api), what happens upstream when an ActorSubscriber dies? Will the stream be cancelled? I use akka 2.4 and akka streams experimental 1.0, and jdk 8

Code looks like this:

```
Materializer chunkerMat = ...

    Source<Buffer, BoxedUnit> bufferSource = ...

    Sink<Buffer, ActorRef> sink = Sink.<Buffer>actorSubscriber(Props.create(new AkkaVertxSubscriber.Creator(response)));

    bufferSource.runWith(sink, chunkerMat);
```

Comment: Unit tests save the world. Please, show your effort - what did you try before asking a question.

Comment: When an actorPublisher dies, the documentation says the stream is cancelled. I presume the same happens with an actorSubscriber, but the docs don't mention it.